# git: always force windows line endings for repo

Tags: git, line-endings, core.autocrlf

I want to force my repo to always use windows line endings, regardless of the user's environment or the setting of `core.autocrlf`.  I've read about using `.gitattributes` to set the line endings, but haven't been able to make that work.  My `.gitattributes` file looks like this:

```
* text=auto
* text eol=crlf
```

After adding this file, I run `git add --renormalize .` and `git add .gitattributes`, then push to remote.  However, this is not overriding my global `core.autocrlf` setting.  What I want is to push my windows line endings to Bitbucket, but what I'm getting is linux line endings in Bitbucket.

How can I force my git client to push Windows line endings for a specific repo, regardless of the user's setting for `core.autocrlf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have two conflicting settings.  `* text=auto` and `* text eol=crlf` are not compatible.  You need to pick one.

However, I regret that neither will do what you want.  Git has no option that is "always convert to CR/LF in the repository".  Your only options control what goes into the working directory.

For example, `* text eol=crlf` will put Windows-style line endings *in the working directory* but will put Unix-style line in the repository.

You can disable line ending configuration entirely by using `* -text`, but this will simply stop doing text conversion and check in the file literally as it exists on disk.  It does not eliminate the possibility of a Unix user rewriting the file with Unix-style line endings.

I would encourage you to *ignore* the contents of the file that exists in the repository, and focus on what you want in working directories instead.  If you always want CR/LF on disk then use `* text eol=crlf`.